# external drive network security

Tags: macos, security, network-user

I work in an office where all user accounts are on a server, the admin has access to all the screens and devices though the network.

**How can I protect the drive I connect to my system from my snoopy admin?**
Encryption is useless since when I enter the password and mount the device, it becomes available when the admin logs in my system remotely.

Answer (score 1):

If the admin has access to the computer remotely while you are logged in then there isnt much you can do about it. As soon as you connect the drive to the computer (encrypted or not - as you said) the drive will become available to anyone who can login to the computer.

The only sure fire way is to bring in a laptop.

Its also worth checking if your company has an IT policy, it may be against the rules to try to 'hide' a connected device from the systems admin or it might be against the rules for the admin to view personal drives connected to machines.

Comment: Hi ORANGE BOX ... I GUESS THERE ISNT THAT MUCH POSSIBLE, THENX FOR THE ANSWER!